# Running 2 applications that read Paradox tables fails on Windows 7 (32 bits)

Tags: perl, delphi, odbc, delphi-5, paradox

I have an application written in Delphi 5 which uses a Paradox ".db" database. My application makes a call to a set of scripts written in Perl and uses ODBC to access the DB tables to collect data and generate XML files.

Everything works fine on my PC (Win 7, 64 bits), but not on a 32-bit Win 7 PC. The Perl script fails and I get the following error:

```
-1305[Pilote ODBC Paradox] le moteur de base de données microsoft Jet n'a pas pu 
trouvé l'objet xxxx.
```

When I close the Delphi application and run the scripts manually it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may faces the problem, i have got the solution. i changed the configuration of BDE as follow:
  `SHAREDMEMSIZE = 1024`.
  `MAXBUFFSIZE = 2048`.
  It is recomanded that  `MAXBUFFSIZE = 2* SHAREDMEMSIZE`.
 And to allow running multiple Applications using the BDE to set the `SHAREDMEMSIZE less than 2048`.